# Find path where PEAR library is installed to place in php.ini?

Tags: ubuntu, pear

How can I find the path where a PEAR library is installed to correct it in php.ini?

Comment: How did you install the library? From an Ubuntu package or the PEAR installer or manually? Did you try doing a `locate -i filename.php` where filename is the name of the package?

Comment: I installed it by typing apt-get install php-pear. I installed docs also through synaptic, but library doesn't seem to in the same directory.

Comment: That package is the overall framework for php / pear, but not a specific pear library.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't clear enough - I looked for a place where PEAR packages are installed. I found that. Thanks.

Comment: For those Googlers who land here because they need to know the path to Pear's PHP files: The best approach is to simply execute (on the command line): `pear config-get php_dir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always find where files are on your system using the locate database like this: `locate -i filename`. However in the case of packages, sometimes browsing is more useful. Since you installed the package using apt-get, you can get a listing of all the files owned by the package and where they went on the system like this:

```
dpkg -L php-pear
```

However that is just the overall pear package system and the wires that connect it to php, I don't think that includes the entire archive of PEAR projects. It is likely that you need to install specific PEAR packages fro each things you need to do. These will either be in the package repository, or you will need to use the pear installer to fetch them.